# VSCode - Renaming Symbol Skips Test Files in Python Project

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In my Python project, when I use VSCode to [rename a symbol](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring#_rename-symbol) the change is not propagated to "test files". More specifically, if a `.py` file lives in a directory named `test` or is named `test_*.py` then the symbol is not renamed in that file. How do I get VSCode to propagate the renamed symbol to test files? There must be some setting I'm not aware of. Or perhaps this is a bug in VSCode's Python extension?

To give a more concrete example of my situation, if I have the following file structure:

```
my_project/
  test/
    __init__.py
    test_thing.py
  __init__.py
  thing.py
  something_else.py
```

Where `thing.py` contains:

```py
class Thing:
    ...
```

And `test_thing.py` contains:

```py
from my_project.thing import Thing
```

If I rename `Thing` to something else, `test_thing.py` does not experience the change even though other, non-test files (e.g. `something_else.py`), are changed to reflect the refactoring.

Here's my full `settings.json`. From what I can tell there isn't anything that should be messing with this:

```json
{
  "[python]": {
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll": "explicit"
    },
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true
  },
  "[toml]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  },
  "cSpell.enabled": false,
  "cSpell.userWords": [
    "callstack",
    "dataframes",
    "docstrings",
    "kwargs",
    "Numpy",
  ],
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
  "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "editor.rulers": [
    88,
    120
  ],
  "evenBetterToml.formatter.alignComments": false,
  "evenBetterToml.formatter.arrayTrailingComma": true,
  "evenBetterToml.formatter.compactEntries": false,
  "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
  "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
  "git.autofetch": true,
  "github.copilot.enable": {
    "*": true,
    "markdown": true,
    "plaintext": true,
    "scminput": false
  },
  "jupyter.askForKernelRestart": false,
  "python.analysis.autoFormatStrings": true,
  "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
  "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
  "python.venvFolders": [
    "~/.mambaforge/envs"
  ],
  "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
  "terminal.integrated.scrollback": 3000,
  "window.nativeTabs": true
}
```

Comment: Check your `.vscode/settings.json`. Are you excluding `test/` somewhere?

Comment: I added my user `settings.json` file (no workspace or project settings). Nothing obvious wrong in there.

Comment: Turns out VSCode is reading PyLint configuration in pyproject.toml and that's what's causing the problem. Still not clear how to prevent that though.